# Windows 10 denying rights to admin account when copying files between directories

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I'm trying to copy one file to another directory. But I get the message that I do not have rights to do so. Problem is I'm the admin. Also tried to copy it via PowerShell, but it throws unauthorized access exception.

I know that Windows 10 likes to do such things, but I haven't seen any solution.

The source directory path I am copying from is: `E:\Copy\ffxiv_dx11.exe`

And the destination directory path is: `E:\Games\SquareEnix\FFXIV\game`

Comment: Define directory and privies

Comment: Make yourself as owner of both directories after which you can provide full access to your account.

Comment: Did you run PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Check if the following article can help with you:https://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/access-denied-when-copying-files-windows-10-8-7.html